# How does Unix search for executable files?

Tags: unix, path

When a file is executed, how does Unix search for it? If there are multiple executable files in PATH with the same name, which one is preferred? Is the current directory included in the search when a file is executed?

Suppose there is a file with name `executable.sh` in the current directory. Would that work if it is executed `$ executed` and `.` is not part of the `PATH`?

Comment: mentioning [`which <executable>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_(command)) command will be useful in this thread.

Answer (score 60):

The $PATH is searched from beginning to end, with the first matching executable being run. So directories at the beginning of $PATH take precedence over those that come later. Executables in the current directory (.) are only executed if . is in $PATH (which it [usually isn't](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-13.html)). There is no implicit inclusion of the current directory in the search path.

Comment: It's weird that, my $PATH don't contains `.`, but it seems would search from current dir first, before check dirs defined in $PATH itself.

Comment: @Eric, that's security consideration to not search current dir (as windows/dos dues). Only if user explicitly added `./` to command

Comment: @coneslayer once that executable is found, are library binaries also searched starting from the beginning?

Answer (score 21):

For files in the current directory, you will want to precede them with `./`, so the command would become `./executable.sh`. You should never have `.` in your PATH as it poses a security risk, among other problems.

Directories that come first in the PATH and searched first.

The **overall order** for searching is like this if I remember correctly:

- aliases
- exported functions
- built-in shell commands
- scripts and binaries in your PATH

Comment: I'd add the hash - remember bash (and maybe other shells) keep a hash of recently used commands to make finding them easier. Sometimes you have to purge the cache (using `hash -r`) if you change your PATH or program locations.

Comment: +1 for the order of searching. Would be nice if you could remember the source of information :)

Answer (score 10):

Though this has been answered well by some others, I'd like to add some thoughts:

1) PATH is only consulted if the executable invoked has no path elements in it.  somecommand would be looked up in $PATH, `./somecommand` or `/usr/bin/somecommand`, or `../../bin/somecommand` just use directory rules, not PATH

> If there are multiple executable files in PATH with the same name which one is preferred?

It stops at the first one it finds, reading $PATH left to right.

> Is current directory included in the search when file is executed?

If the current directory is in PATH then it is searched.  Remember that an empty directory in PATH includes the current directory.  e.g. PATH=:/usr/bin (leading empty) PATH=/usr/bin: (trailing empty) and PATH=/usr/bin::/bin (middle empty) will all effectively include current working directory.

> Suppose there is a file with name executable.sh in a current directory. Would that work if it is executed $ executed and . is not part of the PATH?

It would never find it by searching PATH. If current dir is not in PATH, it won't find it by a PATH lookup.

That said (and sorry to add confusion) if there was an alias or function that ran the command, it would be run. Or if your shell had a location cache, and the executable was in the cache, it may find it. So, it will **never** find it in PATH, but it may be run by other means.

Comment: Thanks for the `cache` note, it almost drive me crazy that the old executable in `/usr/bin/` is still invoked not the new one in `/usr/local/bin`, however it is on the left in the `$PATH` till I logged out, and logged in again.

Comment: @theaccountant in bash you can do ‘hash -r’ to clear the shell cache

Answer (score 4):

To see what your path currently is just type `echo $PATH`, or `printenv PATH`.

Then you'll know the order of searching. If you have multiple files with the same name, just run which ____ to see.

Ex.

> system#> which grep
>
> /usr/bin/grep

a cool way to find files that work like your target is to use apropos:

> apropos grep
>
> bzgrep (1)           - search possibly bzip2 compressed files for a regular expression
>
> egrep (1)            - print lines matching a pattern
>
> fgrep (1)            - print lines matching a pattern
>
> grep (1)             - print lines matching a pattern

and so on...

Comment: Oh yeah -- I forgot the **whereis** function to find ALL instances of a file:

> whereis grep

Comment: grep: /bin/grep /usr/bin/grep /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1.gz

Comment: `whereis` uses a hardcoded list of locations, not `$PATH`.

Comment: @grawity Could you expand on that?

Answer (score -4):

@coneslayer- The default order of finding executable is the current path, built in commands and then the $PATH. So if a function named executable already exists in the pwd, then that is executed.if not then the precedence searches for built in commands of shell and then $PATH

Comment: If you were talking about the Thompson shell, the Mashey shell, or some other fossilized holdover from 40 years ago, you might be right.   But no current, mainstream Unix shell searches the current directory automatically.

Comment: @Scott So the default search path for a command is first built in and then $PATH and searches the CWD only if I give ./    ? Am i right?

Comment: Well, aliases, functions, and builtins.  Then, if you specify a path with the command (including `./`), it searches that directory only; otherwise, it searches `$PATH`.