# Change path for program in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I was using `wget` in Ubuntu from `/usr/bin/wget` (i.e. that's what appeared when I ran `which wget`.) Now, I just downloaded `wget` from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/, and installed it using `./configure; make; sudo make install`.

Now when I ran `which wget`, the output is `/usr/local/bin/wget`. What should I do if I want to change it back to the old one?

Comment: Which one it gets is determined by which one it finds first, which is determined by the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on if you want to keep the new version or not, what you want to do is as simple as either deleting or renaming the new version

`rm /usr/local/bin/wget`
`mv /usr/local/bin/wget /usr/local/bin/wget_new`

The new version got replaced because of the **way the terminal determines which version to use**. There is an **environment variable** called [**PATH**](https://superuser.com/questions/238987/how-does-unix-search-for-executable-files). You can see its value with **`echo $PATH`**. Basically its a **list of paths(folders)**, and when you **try to run `wget`**, it will run through that list and try to find the **first one that has a exe by that name**, and thats the one that gets run.

In your case I'm guessing **PATH** is something like `...:/usr/local/bin/:...:/usr/bin`. Because of this, your new version is **effectively hiding the old version** of `wget`

Comment: So, say I delete the new version, will the system automatically switch back to using the one at `/usr/bin/wget`? How does it determine which one it uses?

Comment: Yup it will revert to that version

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the very clear explanation!