# Why/how does including . in PATH pose a security risk?

Tags: bash, security

I was reading [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/238987/how-does-unix-search-for-executable-files/239144#answer-238992) to understand the inner workings of bash when I saw this:

> You should never have `.` in your PATH as it poses a security risk, among other problems.

and couldn't figure out why this is a security risk and the answer didn't elaborate.